# Software recommendations to combine aerial images

Tags: dji, software

I am taking aerial images which look like this:

[image]

As all of them are taken from approximately the same height and have GPS coordinates (but can overlap a little), I would like to combine all of them in one big image.

This seems like a standard procedure and I assume that there are already available tools (preferably open-source) which can do it, but I am not sure what is the right keywords to find them.

Does anyone know any tool which can do the task (also what is the proper terminology for this task)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful keyword is '[orthophoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthophoto)', and more specifically in this case a mosaic.

An effective open-source tool I have used for this is OpenDroneMap: https://www.opendronemap.org.

I usually combine this with the (closed source but free) Pid4D capture app for collecting the images: https://www.pix4d.com/product/pix4dcapture

To specifically address your DJI tag, I have used both of the above with pictures from Mavic 2 Pros and Inspire 2s; you can also install Pix4D Capture onto a DJI CrystalSky: https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016627091-How-to-install-latest-compatible-APKs-on-DJI-CrystalSky-and-Yuneec-ST16-ST16S-PIX4Dcapture

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try. Do you know if it works with DJI mini2?

Comment: I've not tried with a Mini 2, but in theory any set of geotagged images should work. The limiting factor is likely to be the amount of overlap and having enough distinct features in the images to align them.

Answer (score 1):

Two great options are:

Hugin: https://hugin.sourceforge.io/

ICE: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/image-composite-editor/

I prefer ICE slightly over Hugin.